# ООП В Жизни. Как понять

Tags: python, ооп

Всем привет!

Хочу узнать конкретнее, что такое ооп, если рассказать именно на примере жизни.

И как называют объекты, т.е. классы? Вроде называют сущностями.
Прошу не кидаться тапками, изучаю python и смотрю про объектно-ориентированое мышление.ж

Comment: Даже самых популярных примеров с животными не видели? Они довольно хорошо объясняют.

Comment: Данный ресурс предназначен для конкретных ответов на конкретные вопросы. Просьбы "проведете мне лекцию на заданную тему" здесь не приветствуются, и такие вопросы с высокой вероятностью будут закрыты.

Answer (score 4):

На примере из жизни, так на примере из жизни.
Есть `Котики`(это класс), а есть кот `Барсик`(это экземпляр класса `Котики`). В свою очередь все коты принадлежат к семейству кошачьих. Так же как и гепарды. У них есть что-то общее, но есть и различия (гепарды мурчать не умеют). И получается, что `Кошачьи` - суперкласс для `Котиков` и для `Гепарда`, это уже наследование.
Также котиков можно отнести к `Домашним животным`, как и `Аквариумных рыбок`. Что за теми, что за другими нужно убирать (менять лоток или воду в аквариуме), их нужно кормить. Кормёжку и уборку можно вынести в отдельный интерфейс (не знаю как это происходит в Pyton). После реализации этого интерфейса можно по его типу вызывать разные методы для конкретной реализации. Это полиморфизм.
Тажке котика можно кормить рыбой или кормом. Т.е. можно в классе `Котики` создать метод `покормить` в первой реализации в качестве параметров указать `Рыбу`, во второй - `Сухой корм`. Т.е методов по факту два, но называние у них одно. Это так же полиморфизм.
**UPD**. Забыл про инкапсуляцию.
Каждый `Котик` имеет кличку, окрас, возраст. Эти состояния имеет смысл связать с котом. Т.е. нужно "положить" их в класс `Котиков`. Другими словами инкапсулировать. Так же понятие инкапсуляции связано с сокрытием данных. Например котика крайне нежелательно переименовывать с Барсика, на Мурку (отзываться перестанет), а про окрас вообще молчу. Имеет смысл поле `кличка` сделать private, а доступ к нему получать с помощью специального метода (геттера), который вернёт эту кличку.

Comment: Благодарю, ты - лучший! :)